# Concatenating arrays in laravel-html

Tags: php, laravel

I'm updating an old Laravel app and PHP, and I'm running into an issue with one of the parts of the app that uses [laravel-html](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-html/v2/introduction/). I'm guessing this is because of the way '+' changed from PHP 5.x -> 7.3. Is there a cleaner, better way to write this?

Here is the way it worked in Laravel 5.0.38 / PHP 5.5:

```
{!! Form::select('category', array('ALL'=>'(select)') + $categories, $category) !!}
```

I made this 'fix', which works in Laravel 5.1 / 7.3:

```
{!! Form::select('category', array_merge(array('ALL'=>'(select)'), json_decode(json_encode($categories), true)), $category) !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely not necessary to run your `$categories` through both `json_encode` and `json_decode`. It seems like you're doing that in order to convert `$categories` from a Collection to an Array. If that's the case, you can just call `all()` on the collection to get the underlying Array:

```
{!! Form::select('category', array_merge(['ALL'=>'(select)'], $categories->all()), $category) !!}
```